# Add Styles and Js in Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-5

I'm trying to add `.css` and `.js` file to the laravel project which is quite a normal thing. But its isn't working for me, maybe because I'm in learning phase.

I've a layout file that has **basic html** and I'm trying to add style from other page `@yield('style')`. I don't ve idea about the exact placement of it (someone please guide me) for now, my path is `app\public\css\style.css`

Ways that I already tried:

1) 
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('public/css/style.css') }}">`

2)
   `{!!Html::style('public/css/style.css')!!}`

```
'Html' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

Somebody can help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `asset()` helper function already points to public folder. Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
<img src="{{ asset('img/p1.png') }}" />
```

Comment: and how about fetching images in blade view? I tried -                                       <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/p1.png') }}" />